# Iterate through hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Something very wiered.

This is my code:

```
Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
    data.put("1", new Object[] {"VENDOR_NAME", "COUNTRY_CODE", "PREFIX" , "RATE" , "CURRENCY" });
    data.put("2", new Object[] {10d, "John", 1500000d});
    data.put("3", new Object[] {2d, "Sam", 800000d});
    data.put("4", new Object[] {3d, "Dean", 700000d});

    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for (String key : keyset) {
        System.out.println(key);
    }
```

The result:  3 , 2 ,1 ,4

Why is the order all mixed :S ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the order all mixed :S ?

Because a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) doesn't guarantee any order of iteration of it's element. You will not get any constant order. If you want the insertion order, use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Comment: And if you want alphabetical order, use TreeMap.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):-

> Hash table based implementation of the Map interface. This
>   implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and
>   permits null values and the null key. (The HashMap class is roughly
>   equivalent to Hashtable, except that it is unsynchronized and permits
>   nulls.) This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

That's why you're seeing the order getting all mixed up. As *@Rohit* suggested, try using a `LinkedHashMap` if you want to maintain the order.